# set the element at the middle of the specified container

Tags: javascript, css, layout

In my app,I want to display some information in the middle of the screen when user complete some operation. (just like the flash message)

Now I create a function to make this:

```
var createFlashMessage = function(message, parentDom, time) {
        parentDom = $(parentDom);
        var mask = parentDom.children().first();
        if(!mask.is('message-mask')) {
            mask = $('<div>').addClass('message-mask');
            mask.hide().appendTo(parentDom);
        }
        var messageSpan = $('<span>').html(message).appendTo(mask);
        var conWidth = parentDom.width(), conHeight = parentDom.height();
        messageSpan.css({
            left:Math.floor(conWidth / 2-messageSpan.width()/2),
            top:Math.floor(conHeight / 2-messageSpan.height()/2)
        }).fadeIn(500,function () {
            $(this).delay(time || 3000).fadeOut();
        });
    };
```

This is the css style for the mask div:

---

```
.message-mask 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However when I run it,I found that the mask div can not be positioned at the right position by the container.

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the `z-index` of your pop-up, make it `float-left` then you can do this:

```
messageSpan.css('margin-left', ((conWidth - messageSpan.width()) / 2));
messageSpan.css('margin-top', ((conHeight - messageSpan.height()) / 2));
```

Also the mesage mask should be more like this:

```
.message-mask  {
    position:fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 9998;
}
```

Then when you show the pop-up you un-hide the background.

Comment: fixed position can not work,it is based to the whole window rather than specified element.

Comment: I do not think it matters, because the mask will still cover all of your screen. I think the problem that you have is that your .message-mask div is not inserted in the right position. Try inserting the mask element right after <body> tag, so that it can be fixed and cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, as i am more of a C# guy, but i think it should be more like this.

```
        left:Math.floor((conWidth / 2)-(messageSpan.width() /2)),
        top:Math.floor((conHeight / 2)-(messageSpan.height() /2))
```